# creating archive for my blog website

Tags: php, mysql

my database table is something like :

```
id    year   month 
1     2011   november
2     2011   november
3     2011   october
```

i need to create a query so it return something like that :

```
2011
    november
    november
    october
```

What is the correct query syntax to do it in php script ?

Here is the code i used :

```
<?php

$uid = $_SESSION['uid'];
$sql = "SELECT year, GROUP_CONCAT(month) AS months FROM articles GROUP BY year";
$res = mysql_query ($sql) or die (mysql_error());
if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        foreach ($rows AS $row) {
            echo $row['year'] . "<br>";
            $months = explode(",", $row['months']);
            foreach ($months AS $m) {
                echo $m . "<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This is all about presentation only, so you shouldn't do that right in query.

Comment: what i meant is that i need 2011 to be displayed once and the month column displayed according to that year , everytime i try , i got 2011 repeated 3 times.

Comment: well, just don't output `2011` for the second and third lines :-S

Comment: there shoud be something i can do so i can grab the month belong to this year from all the rows in the table

Comment: yes, there is *something*: it is `if` control structure to decide what and when to do, and `echo` to output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to return a comma-separated list of months:

```
SELECT year, GROUP_CONCAT(month) AS months GROM tbl GROUP BY year

Returns:
2011  november,november,october
```

Or just select both columns and handle the display/presentation in your code:

```
SELECT year, month FROM tbl WHERE year = 2011

Returns
2011   november
2011   november
2011   october
```

In code, loop and only display the year when it changes.

**Update** Since a code example seems warranted...

```
// Results from above GROUP_CONCAT() query already fetched & stored in `$rowset`:    
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
   $rowset[] = $row;
}

// Now $rowset is a 2D array containing all rows.
foreach ($rowset as $row) {
  // Output the year
  echo $row['year'] . "\n";

  // months are comma-separated via GROUP_CONCAT()
  // explode them into an array
  $months = explode(",", $row['months']);
  foreach ($months as $m) {
    // Output the months
    echo $m . "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest to avoid `group_concat` usage since it's length is limited to `group_concat_max_len` even though you probably won't exceed it, but it might be kind of tricky for rookies in `MySQL`

Comment: I only need to display the year once and display all the month along this year!

Comment: @wfareed I understand that. It must be done in PHP, not in your query.

Comment: it returned : 2 2 N N , what is that !

Comment: @wfareed That means you accessed strings as arrays. Given the string "2011", using an array index like [0] would return the first digit, 2.  $rowset above should be a 2D array, as fetched from results. I'll update for more clarity.

Comment: Great :0 That is perfect , Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, I think a simple "ORDER BY" clause would do the trick for you, something similar to:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY year DESC
```

Then, use your scripting language to display the data, a good idea could be (maybe) to fetch the year of the first row, store it in a temporal variable, then loop through the rows and check if the year has changed, if it has, change the value of the aforementioned variable, something like this:

```
$current_year = $data_set[0]['year'];
foreach ( $data_set as $data_row )
{
     $current_year = ( $data_row['year'] != $current_year) ? $data_row['year'] : $current_year;
     //Do something with it and/or the rest of the data
}
```

Hope this was of any help.

Cheers.